# Functions not running on plugin_activation hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create **8** Woo products programmatically via `wp_insert_post` only the first time the plugin is activated. Functions `insert_SB1()` to `insert_SB8()` contain the individual product data. Function `insert_SB1()` has been shown as an example. Adding just one of these products by something only like this without any activation hook / option checking does the job:

```
                $my_post = array(
                    'post_title'     => 'SB: 0 - 60', 
                    'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                    'post_type'      => 'product'
                );
                
                $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
                
                
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Skates', 'product_cat' );
                wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
            
                update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
```

But trying to add all 8 products on activation hook and after checking if an option exist is not working. I have used the `admin_notices` hook to run the insert_SB1-8 functions below because the `init` hook created duplicates when I was test adding just one product out of the activation hook.

This is in my main plugin file:

```
// Activate important functions
include( plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/includes/activation.php');
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'activate_core_functions' );
```

The file `activation.php` contains the function `activate_core_functions`.

```
function activate_core_functions() {
    if ( get_option('my_plugin_activated') ) {        

        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB1');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB2');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB3');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB4');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB5');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB6');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB7');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB8');

        

           function insert_SB1() {
            
            $my_post = array(
                'post_title'     => 'SB: 0 - 60', 
                'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                'post_type'      => 'product'
            );
            
            $post_id = wp_insert_post( $my_post );
            
            
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'Skates', 'product_cat' );
            wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, 'simple', 'product_type');
        
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
            
            // Meta values
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sections', 3);
        
            // Materials related
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bpl', 672);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '1pp', 2);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'plf', 132);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bnp', 152);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'sb', 152);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'cs', 218);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'spl1', 578);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'spl2', 0);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'spl3', 0);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'bwt', 60);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '6hh', 18);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '611hh', 30);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'cp', 0);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'abpl', 175);    
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ab', 1);
        
            add_costs_meta($post_id);
        }




        // Rest of the functions till insert_SB8() are similar below with different product names

        function insert_SB2() {...
        }

        function insert_SB3() {...
        }

        function insert_SB4() {...
        }

        function insert_SB5() {...
        }

        function insert_SB6() {...
        }

        function insert_SB7() {...
        }

        function insert_SB8() {...
        }

        add_costs_meta($post_id){  

            // Costs Related meta vals
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'psc', 1.75);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'pmhc', 45);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'osc', 1.75);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'oabc', 295);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mbc', 1.75);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'mbcp', 0.20);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'wc', 45);
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'ihsc', 75);
        }
    }

    update_option('my_plugin_activated', time());
}
```

I can say that the function `activate_core_functions` is firing properly as the option `my_plugin_activated` does get created in the DB.

Any help would be appreciated, I really worked hard on these, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it working. So I removed these action hooks:

```
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB1');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB2');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB3');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB4');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB5');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB6');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB7');
        add_action('admin_notices', 'insert_SB8');
```

and instead manually executed the function at the end like so:

```
    insert_SB1();
    insert_SB2();
    insert_SB3();
    insert_SB4();
    insert_SB5();
    insert_SB6();
    insert_SB7();
    insert_SB8();
```